# I don’t understand why this won’t print, it says that title is not defined on line 5 even though I defined it in the parenthesis

Tags: python

I defined the problem in the title oops

I have tried so many things I can’t even write them all.

```
def document(title="cool", genre="fiction"):
  print(title+genre)

document(title = "once upon a time ")
document(“awesome”)
document(title+genre)
```

I expect it to print, once upon a time awesome, cool fiction.

Comment: Oh this is still an issue? (You wrote above "I fixed it sorry for bad post.", presumably in answer to a deleted comment, but we don't know. You probably want to delete your response comment. Be aware that comments are ephemeral and tend to get deleted, so other people can't see what was said)

Comment: You're **confusing defining a variable** (e.g. `title = "once upon a time"`) **with specifying a function argument** `document(title="whatever")`. That only specifies the argument passed into `document()` function, it doesn't define a local variable called `title`. And by "inside the parenthesis" you mean "in my function call to document()"

Comment: I’m sorry I am new to this can u explain with examples

Comment: Yes, see my answer

Comment: StackOverflow is not a good place to try to learn the basics of a language from the ground up. You would be better served to review whatever book or lecture series it is you're learning from, and if you have a specific question about what the book/lecture says, a better place to ask is for example http://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython.

Answer (score 1):

You defined a function which takes two arguments named `title` and `genre`. These two arguments are only accessible within your function as local variable. Since these variables aren't declared outside the function, they can not be accessed.

```py
def document(title="cool", genre="fiction"):
  print(title+genre)

#declaration of variables
title="foo"
genre="bar"
document(title, genre)
```

Comment: How would I fix this, and then what is the point of a defined function?

Comment: "what is the point of a... function?" It gives a name to the steps that are taken in the definition, and allows you to reuse those steps.

Comment: If you want to have variables with these names at your main scope, you can declare **title** and **genre** outside the function, as I declared at above code.

Comment: I mean what is the point of defining the arguments in the parentheses.

Comment: They are inputs to the function. The function takes some inputs, manipulate them and returns output. Arguments can have default value. Both genre and title variables have default value, so it's not required to pass that argument to the function.

Comment: I think your answer can add the following contents: If you want to use the default value of those two parameters, you can just call `document()`.

Comment: Yes, However, In this answer, I just wanted to show the difference between local and global variables.

Answer (score 0):

You're **confusing defining a variable** (e.g. `title = "once upon a time"`) **with specifying a function argument** `document(title="whatever")`. The latter only specifies the argument passed into `document()` function, it doesn't define a local variable called `title`.

And by "inside the parenthesis" you mean "in my function call to `document()`"

One solution is to do the following:

```
title = "once upon a time "  # <-- actually define a local variable
genre = "Mongolian puppetry"

document(title)  # now you can use that variable in your function call
document(“awesome”)
document(title+genre)  # ...and reuse that variable again
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def document(title="cool", genre="fiction"):
```

This means that the function has two arguments, named `title` and `genre`. Each of these has a default value provided, that will be filled in if the caller does not provide them. This is **not** "defining `title`" in the way that you seem to be thinking of it. Each function *has its own entirely separate set of names for things*, as well as the global set of names for things.

```
    print(title+genre)
```

This means that whatever values were provided, whether they were from the caller or the default values, will be concatenated and printed.

```
document(title = "once upon a time ")
```

This says to call the function and use `"once upon a time "` as the value for `title`. The value for `genre` is not provided, so the default value of `"fiction" is used. Thus,`once upon a time fiction` is printed.

```
document("awesome")
```

This says to call the function and use `"awesome"` as the value for the first parameter. That parameter is the `title` parameter, so `"awesome"` is used as the value for `title`. As before, the value for `genre` is still `"fiction"`, so `awesomefiction` is printed.

Note that when the function runs, `title` is the name that is being used by the function for the string `"awesome"`, even though you didn't say anything about `title` when you called the function.

```
document(title+genre)
```

This says to use whatever are the values of `title` and `genre` *in the calling context*, as the value for the first parameter. But there are no such defined names outside the function. The function's parameters are *completely separate* and have *no meaning whatsoever* here. You get a `NameError` because the names in question are not defined.